# Access to webpage from other computer giving error

Tags: apache-httpd

I installed `apache2` following some tutorial,  but I got stuck and am not sure if the server has been installed correctly.

I want to access my shell outside the network. I think I port forwarded and here is the [website](http://asus.ns360.info/) to access the shell.

I am not able to access it from my computer.

Here is the error in `apache2:`

```
[....] Restarting web server: apache2[Thu Apr 18 00:44:44 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 18 00:44:44 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting .[Thu Apr 18 00:44:46 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 18 00:44:46 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Please help me... I am stuck...can you people access the shell in the website?

Comment: I am also getting this error as in the website when i open that 503 service not available type error..

Comment: the person who gave voted my question please also answer it...I am not able to solve it only.

Comment: Can you access it from its IP inside your network?

Comment: no that is what my laptop is not opening this page can you see the website?

Comment: Yes, I can see the website, it takes a while to load though.

Comment: Not sure if you meant for this to happen, but when I opened your website I got a malware warning.

Comment: i can access it now there was some problem with apache configuration i think thank you for helps.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx even i get the warning when access from outside network today why is the warning coming? is there virus in the program?

Comment: @Enthusiast I *really* doubt that someone SQL injected you (assuming that you use SQL for forms.) Maybe you should give us your apache source code... or you can restart/reinstall your server to get rid of the malware.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx no not using sql forms.I am using a software shellinabox and also running it from virtual host at apache to redirect  to port.i dont know what you are talking about SQL injections and all.I am not written any code

Answer (score 2):

if anyone also experiencing same problems then here is what the problem with me was.

i copied the code from tutorial and the location in configuration file in apache was not set correctly.

i changed to this and it started working after that only.

```
<Location />
        allow from all
</Location>
```

the file to change was in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/virtualhosts.conf`

the previous warning is still not gone but i am still able to access the pi from everywhere so i think that error was only warning or something

some people are saying i am spreading virus but i only wanted some help.i am only following tutorial and asking help for my pi.i don;t even know how to make viruses otherwise i wouldnt be wanting help for easy things like this.

Comment: Well don't for finding the solution. I think the malware warning was just the web browser being slightly over zealous.